# Get the list of CMake configure_file calls

Tags: cmake, build-system

A bit of context first - I'm working on converting a CMake build system to an internal build system. For this I iterate `BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS` and use `get_property` to get all the properties I need and everything works fine, except some files are missing from the build. After checking the CMakeLists.txt files from the original build system I realized `configure_file` is used in many and quite random places.

I ***assume*** CMake is storing `configure_file` calls internally. If this is the case, is it possible to access this?

Comment: "I assume CMake is storing `configure_file` calls internally." - I don't expect CMake to store these calls. (But it definitely store template files which are used in that calls in [CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS.html) property). The simplest way to collect calls of some function is **redefine** that function. In the redefining function you could implement the logic which you need. For call original function in redefined one, use underscore-prefixed name (`_configure_file`).

Comment: This worked and solved my problem. Can you please turn this into an answer?

Comment: Ideally, what format do you want the information about the calls to be in? Do you care where the list is stored to (can it be to a file? can it be in a CMake variable? can it be `message()`-ed to the console?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **redefine** `configure_file` as a function (or macro) at the beginning of the project's `CMakeLists.txt`. That way allows you to run arbitrary code every time the function is invoked in the project.

Inside redefining function you could implement the logic which you need. For call original function in the redefining one, use underscore-prefixed name (`_configure_file`):

```
function(configure_file input output)
  # ...
  # Do something with the 'output' file. E.g. add it to the global list.
  # ...

  # After custom processing call original function with all parameters.
  _configure_file(${input} ${output} ${ARGN})
endfunction()
```

---

Note, that generally redefining CMake functions is discouraged (at least, the underscored version of a function is an **undocumented** feature). But for **debugging** purposes it looks reasonable. Moreover, debugging was the primary reason to introduce such underscored functions: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23482

Answer (score 2):

Tsyvarev's answer of redefining `configure_file` works, but be aware that Craig Scott (one of the maintainers of CMake) has [an article recommending against redefining CMake commands](https://crascit.com/2018/09/14/do-not-redefine-cmake-commands/). Using the internal underscore-prefixed commands is relying on undocumented behaviour that can change in future versions. Using this trick can also result in infinite recursion.

While for your scenario it works fine, if you want to avoid using that trick, you can use the [`--trace*` arguments to the `cmake` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options).

[`--trace`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-trace) puts cmake in trace mode, which will print a trace of all calls made and from where.

[`--trace-expand`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-trace-expand) is like `--trace`, but with variables expanded.

[`--trace-format=<format>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-trace-format) lets you choose between `human` (a human readable format (the default value)), or `json-v1`, which prints JSON.

[`--trace-redirect=<file>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-trace-redirect) puts cmake in trace mode and redirects trace output to a file instead of stderr.

So you could use the human format and grep for `configure_file`, or you could use the `json-v1` format and write a script in a lanugage of your choice to search the JSON for calls to `configure_file`. You could also possibly use a comandline tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to do the search.